# Testing Angular Service with Jasmine: Failed to instantiate module app

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am trying to create a Simple Unit Test using Jasmine for an Angular Service.
But when I am running the Test via Karma, I am getting the following error:

```
Failed to instantiate module app
```

And I don't know why I am getting this error. I Googled and tried to apply the below solutions. But none worked.

- I tried changing the sequence of files in the karma.conf.js.
- I tried writing the Unit test in different ways. I mean injecting the service in different ways.

But the error remains the same.

It is a very simple code. Please find the code below for reference:

**string.service.js**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory("stringService", stringService)

    function stringService() {

        return {
            checkForAlphaNumeric: checkForAlphaNumeric,
        };

        function checkForAlphaNumeric(string) {
            var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
            return regex.test(string);
        }
    }
})();
```

**string.service.spec.js**

```
describe("-----> String Service", function () {

    var stringService;
    beforeEach(function () {
        angular.mock.module('app');
        inject(function ($injector) {
            stringService = $injector.get('stringService');
        });
    });

    it("--> stringService should be Defined.", function () {
        expect(stringService).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

**karma.conf.js**

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  //External
  './node_modules/angular/angular.js', // Angular Framework
  './node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js', // Loads the Module for Tests
  './node_modules/@uirouter/angularjs/release/angular-ui-router.js', // UI-Router
  './node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js',

  //Sub Modules
  './app/authentication/authentication.module.js',

  //Main Module
  './app/app.module.js', // Angular App

  //Controllers
  './app/authentication/login.controller.js',

  //Services and Factories
  './app/services/string.service.js',

  //Specs
  './app/licensing/licensing.controller.spec.js',
  './app/services/string.service.spec.js'
],
```

- Interchanging the module and sub-module reference is also not working.
- Putting the module and sub-module reference before or after the controllers and service is also not working.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out what was wrong in my scenario. Let me explain:

- My **app** module has several dependencies.
- My **string service** was part of **app** module.
- Now, when you want to test the **string service**, you have to reference all (means all) the **app** module dependencies in the **karma.conf.js** file section. Even the ones you are not using for the service.
- In my case, I was not referencing the **qrcode** dependency as I was not using **qrcode** in the **string service**.
- And this missing reference was creating the problem. And hence the **karma** was not able to instantiate the module **app**.

Hope this helps somebody.